# PWM on GPIO4 + Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi, esp8266, gpio, nodemcu

Проблема с платой типа NodeMCU с распаяным ESP8266 непосредственно на плате. Заключается в потере сигнала Wi-Fi при выставлении значения ШИМ отличного от максимального или минимального на выходе GPIO4. Для разработки используется ESP8266_rtos_sdk. Проблема проявляется только при использовании GPIO4. На подобной плате с модулем ESP12-E (экранированный) таких проблем не замечено. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и находил решение?

Comment: Try to ask in russian here.

Comment: Это или частота пвм наводится на антенну или софт блок в коде. Попробуй микросхеме приделать шапку из фольги или поменять частоту пвм. Возможно ещё проблема в том что микросхемка неправильно обвязанна

Comment: @eri пробовал поменять частоту, не помогает